# simple while issue (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Can any body shed some light on why I am not able to stop and start this loop?

```
 <input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
 <input type="reset" value="stop" onClick="stop()">

var startLottery = false;

while(startLottery){
setInterval(function(){automateLottery()},120);
startLottery;
};

var start = function(){
startLottery = true;    
};

var stop = function(){
startLottery = false;   
};
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to put the interval in a while.

Comment: And, what's the point of the last `startLottery` in the loop? It'll just evaluate a boolean and do nothing with it.

Comment: @UllerUller Can you select one of the answers below as correct, so the question will be close?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1**

A `while` loop will only execute when the operand evaluates to `true`.

However, you start off with your `startLottery` variable equal to `false`.

So the `while` loop will never execute.

**Problem 2**

At no point are you actually changing the value of the `startLottery` variable, so even if the loop did execute, it would never terminate.

Comment: This won't really help. The problem is that he is using a looping structure instead of set/clearInterval.

Comment: Thanks guys, All I am trying to do is stop and start a loop with my stop and start buttons.

Comment: I was hoping that when I press the start button I would change startLottery to true and therefore start the loop??

Comment: @UllerUller I believe jbabey is correct.  I hope you see WHY what you did is not a proper while loop.  This is an important thing to understand. But jbabey has code that will do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot start and stop a loop like that. You need to use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`:

JS:

```
var lotteryInterval;

var start = function(){
    lotteryInterval = setInterval(lotteryFunc, 120);
};

var stop = function(){
    clearInterval(lotteryInterval);
};

var lotteryFunc = function () {
    automateLottery();
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
<input type="reset" value="stop" onClick="stop()">
```

Edit: [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3XwD8/).

Comment: Thank you, going to try this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for this (assuming you do have an `automateLottery` function):

```
var timer;

var start = function(){
    timer = setInterval(automateLottery, 120);
};

var stop = function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
};

start();
```

Comment: Yep that's the one. Thanks bFavaretto

Answer (score 0):

If what you provided for code is exactly as I see it, the `while` loop will never be entered.  The page will be rendered (the `input`s) and then the variable `startLottery` will be set to `false`.  Next, the loop will evaluate the expression (which will always return `false`) and never actually enter the loop.